# Is there a practical limit to the size of a piece of data with 0 statistical redundancy?

Tags: statistical-learning

I was just wondering, just because I tend to wonder about these sort of things in my spare time, if there are any data pieces that are 1Gig+ that have 0 Statistical Redundancy? (i.e., uncompressible with lossless compression.)
Is it even possible for a file larger than a few bytes to have such a trait? Is that property possible at all, or merely theoretical?

Anyway, please let me know if such a thing would be possible, and, if feasible, please link me to a place where I could view such a piece of data. Google gave me nothing.

Might as well include the Wikipedia page about statistical redundancy: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy (information theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_%28information_theory%29)

Comment: +1 for just tending "to wonder about these sort of things in [your] spare time", I can see how your earned your moniker. On a different note, I suspect this Q may be a better fit on either [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or [theoretical computer science.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) (please don't cross-post, though). You may want to flag your Q & ask a mod to migrate it, if you don't get a satisfactory answer here after a while.

Comment: @gung Funny you should say that... http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157525/202692

Comment: I would have thought that the frequency of such an occurrence would be quite likely to be related to the frequency of finding large prime numbers. Even multiples of two or three quite large primes would be hard for a normal compression program to factor.

Comment: What about a sequence of bits generated by a Bernoulli process with p=0.5? The redundancy should be zero, right?

Comment: There are potentially over 1 million characters in utf16, which means you'd need over 2mb just to list them all in any order. Couldn't you just find 500 unrelated permutations, and that'd do it? Or would they still be compressible in binary?

Comment: @mogron That... is pure genius. I had never thought about that idea before. However, with that idea, there is the issue of a possible long string of 0's appearing, and then run-length encoding could squeeze it down...

Comment: @naught101 Yes, that's the trouble with using characters. You never know what annoying complications the bits you aren't paying attention to will get you. All the characters have some mathematical relationship with each other... I would, however, give you points for trying if you could get a 2MB string that had no statistical redundancy. :)

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Yes, I guess you'd have to use some kind of limit based approach. Something like: "for any compression algorithm, the compression ratio of the Bernoulli-generated bit sequence approaches 1 as the length of the sequence approaches infinity." If you have a fixed, finite sequence S, there always exists a compression algorithm that compresses this sequence to just 1 bit. (for example, the algorithm could simply map the given sequence to "1", and prefix any other sequence with a "0"). Note that redundancy is defined via a limit.

Comment: @mogron I actually was sort of considering compression algorithims that use predefined strings (e.g., "&superLongString" = {text of "War and Peace"}) to be "cheater" algorithms. I was thinking more along the lines of something a bit more straightforward, so to speak.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I conjecture that for every fixed, finite sequence, there exists a "non-cheating" algorithm that can compress this sequence. Of course one would need a formal definition of "non-cheating" compression algorithms to prove this.

Comment: @mogron Basically, a "non-cheater" algorithm can define any piece of data that it wants to be equivalent to any other piece of data that it wants, or it can define something more complex than that, but the catch is that the definition would be stored in header-type data in the beginning of the compressed file, therefore contributing to the filesize. So you can define a relatively complex algorithm, as long as it saves you more then it would take to define it.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude After some research, I believe my conjecture that any sequence is compressible with some algorithm is wrong. I also think that Kolmogorov complexity leads to a good formalization of your problem. I'll put an answer up in a few minutes.

Comment: Just iterate : compress a piece of data, then compress the result, then again... You'll get quickly something that can't be compressed anymore (with the same algorithm). If your original data is big enough, the uncompressible result will be big -- as big as you want.

Comment: Oh... I never thought of that before... Ha, ha. Just keep compressing it... Wow.. I feel so stupid for not thinking of that before... :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll ty to answer the question in terms of [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), which is the length of the smallest description of a finite sequence, given a fixed description language. A sequence is called Kolmogorov random, if the Kolmogorov complexity is at least as big as the length of the sequence (i.e., the sequence is incompressible).

For your problem, we use the set of programs on a fixed universal Turing machine as description language. Without loss of generality, we may assume that the universal Turing machine uses a binary alphabet.
For each natural number $n>0$, there exists a Kolmogorov random sequence. The proof is simple: There are $2^n$ sequences of length $n$, but only $2^{n-1}$ programs of length less than $n$. So by the pigeonhole principle, there must be some sequences -- in fact, at least $2^n - 2^{n-1} = 2^{n-1}$ sequences -- of length $n$ that are incompressible.

This proof is of course not constructive. Also, it is not computable if a given sequence is Kolmogorov random.

**Update**

To make a connection to statistical redundancy:
If you generate a sequence by some random process, the Kolmogorov complexity divided by the length of the sequence converges to the entropy of the generating process (as the length of the sequence goes to infinity). Thus, a sequence generated by a Bernoulli process with p=0.5 will be "Kolmogorov random in the limit".

Answer (score 1):

I’ll improve shortly on my above comment: If a compression algorithm is fixed, an arbitrary large non-compressible (with this algorithm) piece of data can be obtained just by iterating the algorithm. If a cycle appear before hitting the desired size, pick some starting point out of this cycle, and try again.

$\def\N\{\mathbb N^*}$Details. Considering that data are strings of 0 and 1, a file is (after prefixing it with a 1) nothing more than a (non zero) integer. The length of a file $n\in \N*$ is $\log(n)$. A compression algorithm is an injective function from $\N$ to $\N$ (it has to be injective to ensure decompression is possible).
We say that $n$ is non-compressible if $\log(n) < \log(f(n))$.

I will distinct two cases (not absolutely necessary bit the first case is nicer) First, assume $f$ is non surjective and you know some $n \notin f(\N)$ (this is quite reasonable for practical examples). As $f$ is injective, if the orbit $f^{(k)}(n)$ is ultimately cyclic, it has to go through $n$ again. As  $n \notin f(\N)$, this is impossible: so the orbit is not ultimately cyclic, and it has to go through arbitrary big numbers. More precisely, the length of the successive numbers have two increase from time to time, so this sequence contains an infinite amount of non-compressible numbers. Some have to be larger than the prescribed size.

In the general case, well, pick up a number $n$, and iterate. If you meet a non-compressible number of the desired size before hitting $n$ again, you are done. In the other case, pick up a starting point out of the cycle, and try again. You iterate this, each time excluding all the cycles previously described. The sequence generated also contains an infinite amount of non-compressible numbers.